# How to do cascade splitting with C# Linq - multiple foreach split

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, split

These are the values i want to split the string cascadingly

```
List<string> lstsplitWord = new List<string> { ",", "=", "،", "أو", "او", "/", "." };
```

I have written them as like this but i am assuming that there must be more elegant Linq solution for this

```
    foreach(var part1 in srSplitPart.Split(',')) {
     foreach(var part2 in part1.Split('=')) {
      foreach(var part3 in part2.Split('،')) {
       foreach(var part4 in part3.func_Split_By_String("أو")) {
        foreach(var part5 in part4.func_Split_By_String("او")) {
         foreach(var part6 in part5.Split('/')) {
          foreach(var part7 in part6.Split('.')) {
           if (part7.Length < 3)
            continue;
           string srTrans = part7.FixArabic().func_Special_Trim();

           srTemp.AppendLine($ "{srTitle} > {srTrans} \t {irTransLevel}");
           irTransLevel++;
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

C# .net 4.6.2

special split function

```
public static List<string> func_Split_By_String(this string Sentence, string srReplace)
{
    return Sentence.Split(new string[] { srReplace }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is so nested I can't even tell what you're trying here

Comment: isn't the Split() overload enough? just pass lstsplitWord. .Split(lstsplitWord)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just iteratively split every element to smaller parts in a given order:

```
string originalString = ...;
List<string> separators = new List<string> { ",", "=", "،", "أو", "او", "/", "." };

string[] result = new[] { originalString };

foreach (var separator in separators)
{
    result = result.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
}

result = result
    .Where(x => x.Length >= 3)
    .Select(x => x.FixArabic().func_Special_Trim())
    .ToArray();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    srTemp.AppendLine($ "{srTitle} > {srTrans} \t {irTransLevel}");
    irTransLevel++;
}
```

At the beginning, your array will contain only your original string.
After the first `foreach` iteration array will contain original string separated by ",".
After the second `foreach` iteration every comma-separated part will be separated by `=`.
It will repeat until `result` array contains only strings separated by all given separators. It then applies `Length >= 3` condition and `FixArabic()` and `func_Special_Trim()`.

**Update:** I have just understood one thing - applying all separators in a given order results into **the same** string array as simply applying all separators without order.

So, actually, you can just do:

```
string originalString = ...;
string[] separators = new[] { ",", "=", "،", "أو", "او", "/", "." };

string[] result = originalString
    .Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(x => x.Length >= 3)
    .Select(x => x.FixArabic().func_Special_Trim())
    .ToArray();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    srTemp.AppendLine($ "{srTitle} > {srTrans} \t {irTransLevel}");
    irTransLevel++;
}
```

Comment: ty for detailed answer :)

Comment: What about `func_Split_By_String("أو")`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy According to the name of a function, I was sure (for some reason) that it doesn't contain any special logics and the OP just implemented it because `String.Split()` has no `Split(string)` overloading. Now I understand that I may be absolutely wrong. Anyway, in case of code 1, adding "if (someCondition) use specialSplit else use string.split" would solve the problem.

Comment: for the second answer, i need to write another overload function though. because i should be able to split by string as well. i have added func_Split_By_String to the question

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG No, just make some universal function which will use either `String.Split` or your special function and encapsulate this logic in it. Use this function everywhere instead of spreading this logic across the whole application. Imho :)

Comment: If you need result just for looping, you can leave it as enumerable and avoid creating new array.